# Do heat sinks/multi-hack mods work on enemy portals?

Tags: ingress

If there was an enemy portal stacked with 2 VR heat sinks and 2 VR Multi-hacks. Would I also benefit from the mod bonuses?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you will :)

Mods efficiency is not "faction related", a "great" (high level, good mods) portal will be great for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you would get the same benefit from the portal mods as someone from the other faction that was hacking the portal.

There are definitely good reasons to hack enemy portals, such as:

- if you're in need of items and the nearest friendly portal is far away
- if you're in need of AP (since you get 100 AP per hack)
- if you're in need of high level items and the enemy portal is a higher level than you could get it to by deploying your resonators on it

Keep in mind though, it doesn't always make sense to hack enemy portals since:

- sometimes you won't receive any items from a hack and then you've used XM to hack it for nothing
- enemy portals zap you of your XM based on the table below

> Portal Level | Damage If It Zaps You
>
> 1 | 75
>
> 2 | 125
>
> 3 | 175
>
> 4 | 238
>
> 5 | 300
>
> 6 | 400
>
> 7 | 500
>
> 8 | 600

Comment: My idea was to make a level 7 portal with multi hack mods and flip it. Our enlightened agents won't take it down and our low levels can farm it ofr ap

Comment: It's makes sense if it's a portal that the enlightened are always capturing. Also your low level will get 100 AP each hack. But, you have to worry about 1. communication on your team not to take it down. Everyone would need to know. This is especially hard if you live in a city with a lot of tourists or other traffic through the city. Resistance tourists might see it and take it down because they see an L7 enlightened portal. 2. its placement. If it's in an area where enlightened agents could use it to create a field or establish a strategic link to block your fields/links, it could be a bad

Comment: idea. 3. attracting enlightened agents. Feeding enlightened agents items without XM loss is a good way to get them to come by and knock out your other portals with all the gear you've supplied them from the portal you created. Try to make sure it's far enough away from any farms your faction maintains.